# NServiceBus chokes on Generic DTO

Tags: generics, nservicebus, dto

If I have a DTO that looks like this:

```
public class MyMessage<TContent> : Message
{
    public TContent Content {get;set;}
}
```

NServiceBus chokes trying to dynamically generate concrete definition for TContent at startup - which's obviously impossible - unless it's smart enough to not only parse Types but also opcodes and I don't think we're there yet.

Is there a way around this or I simply can't have generics in my DTOs?

Comment: At the moment it is not supported. If you feel that it should be please send create an issue https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/new and tell us why you really need it.

Comment: It should be, or at least the error should be consistent, but it isn't. The error message is cryptic and inconsistent. Sometimes it err out at initialization other times on the receiving end. Using certain configuration (non-autosubscribe) actually lets you do this w/o any error. A proper documentation would have gone a long way in addition to a more robust code.