# NServiceBus Commands/Handlers with Generic Type Parameter

Tags: generics, nservicebus

I tried searching through the nsb documentation but didn't find anything relating to type generics. My feeling is that the lack of it being mentioned is an indication that it isn't supported.

It appears that old versions didn't support this as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258936/nservicebus-chokes-on-generic-dto).

Here's a simple example of what I'd like to do:

```
public class Create<T> : ICommand
{
    public T Entity { get; set; }
}

public class CreateHandler<T> : IHandler<Create<T>>
{
    public Task Handle(Create<T> message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        // insert into database
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if this is now possible?

I'm using nsb v6.

Comment: maybe https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1549

Comment: good find, so it looks like it can work, I'll just need to manually set up the MEMs in code vs via app.confg

Comment: It is really an anti pattern to build generic handlers, why do you want to do it?

Comment: There's a few cases were it would dramatically decrease the amount of code written while maintaining clarity of intent at the call sites. For example, inserting a record into a database. IMO, it's useful anytime the generic type argument is irrelevant to the behavior of the handler. Similar can be achieved using type erasure, but would be nice to use generics.

Comment: I've seen this question often. I think it should be the choice of the developer to use generics or not. The argument that it is anti-pattern may not outweigh the time it saves not having to create 200 handlers and commands for crud operations when there are 200 entities to manage instead 1 command and handler.